# is sh a symbolic link to bash?

Tags: symbolic-link

I am new to Ubuntu. I want to know if sh is a symbolic link to bash. Similarly, if "/usr/bin/awk" is a symbolic link to gawk and if "/usr/bin/yacc" is a symbolic link to bison or a small script that executes bison. How do I do it?

Answer (score 4):

To know what a command really is, you can do this:

```
$ which sh
/bin/sh
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 déc.  13 22:34 /bin/sh -> dash
```

So, sh is a symbolic link to /bin/dash.

Comment: You can also use readlink e.g. `readlink -f $(which awk)`